# Show popup on "Unlocking" incremental achievement in Play game services

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am working with Google play game services for Android (11.6.0).I have set the setViewForPopups(view) method.
I am trying to use achievements.
When I unlock the achievement like so

```
Games.getAchievementsClient(this,GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).unlock(getString(R.string.my_achievement_id));
```

a popup is generated that says the achievement has been unlocked.
However,If I use the incremental achievement type and unlock it like so

```
  Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        .increment(getString(R.string.my_achievement_id), 1);
```

It does not generate a popup.
What can I do to generate a pop up for incremental achievements?

Comment: Try to visit the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/AchievementsClient#increment(java.lang.String, int)) and access if your code complied in the conditions given. Also take note that there is this function you can use [`incrementImmediate(String, int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/AchievementsClient.html#incrementImmediate(java.lang.String, int)) if you need the operation to attempt to communicate to the server immediately or need to have the status code delivered to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Popup for incremental achievement shown only if incremented value is enough to unlock achievement. Popup is shown not for each increment, but for final unlocking only.